# How Atlas differentiated that the di-photon produced was not by a graviton but instead by a Higgs Boson decay?

Tags: particle-physics, standard-model, quantum-gravity, higgs

The Wikipedia article here, https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Higgs_boson#Confirmation_of_existence_and_current_status , confirms (see "zero spin requirement" table row test) that the graviton (i.e. theorized spin-2 particle) can decay into a di-photons γγ pair spin-1. The question now is, (the answer was not very clear in the related  [Atlas paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269313006527?via%3Dihub), see section 4 of paper H-->γγ) how they differentiated that the di-photons observed was not due to they decay of spin-2 graviton but rather a spin-0 Higgs Boson?

Comment: As the paper says, they inferred this from the angular distribution of the decay products (figure 2). Also, you’ve mixed things up a bit. The graviton is massless so it certainly can’t be confused with the Higgs boson — they are talking about some _massive_ spin 2 particle which is unrelated to the graviton.

Answer (score 3):

There are many reasons. The graviton isn't just some particle. There are a great number of properties a particle needs to have for it to be the graviton.

1. The graviton is massless (see gravitational waves moving at the speed of light and precision measurements generally being in agreement with GR). This was a resonance at a mass consistent with the Higgs boson.
2. It was determined to be spin $0$. The graviton is spin $2$.
3. The coupling for the graviton is proportional to $G_N$, and so such events will be completely undetectably rare.
4. The Higgs production rate was consistent with, rather, the standard model predictions for the Higgs couplings.

I'd encourage you to open a quantum field theory book. It's a difficult subject, but it's fascinating and getting through it is really rewarding. It seems like you have an impression that we can just imagine anything with particles and claim it as a possibility. Quantum field theory makes very specific, clear predictions about the implications of certain particles' existence.

Answer (score -1):

According to my review of the literature the specific theory (see equation 4 in the [Atlas paper](https://www.sciencedirect.com/science/article/pii/S0370269313006527?via%3Dihub#br0270)) is based on the cited in the Atlas article of 1977 reference https://journals.aps.org/prd/abstract/10.1103/PhysRevD.16.2219 citation [27] in the related Atlas paper (see section 4). Notice that at that time Higgs Boson was not yet experimentally confirmed and any pair production is assumed to come effectively from the decay of a virtual photon.

Virtual photons and in general virtual Bosons are allowed to have mass and in general all virtual particles by definition are unstable.

Higgs Boson and the graviton Boson are actually both virtual Boson particles of the vacuum and the only reason why the Higgs Boson spin-0 was promoted to a Standard Model (SM) particle is because it was indirectly experimentally confirmed by its theorized decay byproducts particular characteristics observed at 2012 (Boson byproducts) and 2013 (lepton byproducts) at LHC CERN.

On the other hand a massive virtual graviton spin-2 Boson is not confirmed so far. Another difference is that although the Higgs spin-0 Boson is an unstable elementary particle, the graviton is theorized to have a stable (i.e. non-virtual) spin-2 massless version further supported by the LIGO experiment results that show that gravity waves travel at the speed of light $c$.

On the Atlas paper (see section 4 and fig.2) the theoretical fitting of the observed data was expected to see most of the di-photon production $γγ$ events to occur preferably at an angle close to $θ$ **$180^\circ$** *(i.e. $90^\circ$ from the z-axis)* between the two γ-photons produced whereas for the virtual massive graviton the expected angle $θ$ was close to **$90^\circ$** *(i.e. $45^\circ$ from the z-axis)*.

The collected data from the Atlas detector fitted more to the Higgs Boson spin-0 case (see fig.2 section 4). Thus, the discovered particle was the spin-0 Higgs Boson taking also into account the observed effective total mass of its decay byproducts.